# Microsoft Graph : How to switch off "Show in global address list" for new user

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I create new user using Microsoft graph

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0

it works fine. But I want, that user should not be in Global address list, I want to have switch off this feature for created user:

[image]

I look at documentation, none such option in `User` object, did not find for `Contact` object. Any way to set "Show in global address list" = false using Graph API (by default it's `true` for created user)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all settings for a user are surfaced in the user object in the Microsoft Graph. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0

Sometimes its useful to go to the CDSL definition of MIcrosoft Graph by using https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=$metadata&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com

You'll see this entityType

```
<EntityType Name="user" BaseType="microsoft.graph.directoryObject" OpenType="true">
        <Property Name="accountEnabled" Type="Edm.Boolean" />
        <Property Name="ageGroup" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="assignedLicenses" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.assignedLicense)" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="assignedPlans" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.assignedPlan)" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="businessPhones" Type="Collection(Edm.String)" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="city" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="companyName" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="consentProvidedForMinor" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="country" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="department" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="displayName" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="employeeId" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="faxNumber" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="givenName" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="imAddresses" Type="Collection(Edm.String)" />
        <Property Name="jobTitle" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="legalAgeGroupClassification" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="licenseAssignmentStates" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.licenseAssignmentState)" />
        <Property Name="mail" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="mailNickname" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="mobilePhone" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="onPremisesDistinguishedName" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="onPremisesExtensionAttributes" Type="microsoft.graph.onPremisesExtensionAttributes" />
        <Property Name="onPremisesImmutableId" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="onPremisesLastSyncDateTime" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" />
        <Property Name="onPremisesProvisioningErrors" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.onPremisesProvisioningError)" />
        <Property Name="onPremisesSecurityIdentifier" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="onPremisesSyncEnabled" Type="Edm.Boolean" />
        <Property Name="onPremisesDomainName" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="onPremisesSamAccountName" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="onPremisesUserPrincipalName" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="otherMails" Type="Collection(Edm.String)" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="passwordPolicies" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="passwordProfile" Type="microsoft.graph.passwordProfile" />
        <Property Name="officeLocation" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="postalCode" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="preferredLanguage" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="provisionedPlans" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.provisionedPlan)" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="proxyAddresses" Type="Collection(Edm.String)" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="showInAddressList" Type="Edm.Boolean" />
        <Property Name="state" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="streetAddress" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="surname" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="usageLocation" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="userPrincipalName" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="userType" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="mailboxSettings" Type="microsoft.graph.mailboxSettings" />
        <Property Name="aboutMe" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="birthday" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="hireDate" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="interests" Type="Collection(Edm.String)" />
        <Property Name="mySite" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="pastProjects" Type="Collection(Edm.String)" />
        <Property Name="preferredName" Type="Edm.String" />
        <Property Name="responsibilities" Type="Collection(Edm.String)" />
        <Property Name="schools" Type="Collection(Edm.String)" />
        <Property Name="skills" Type="Collection(Edm.String)" />
        <Property Name="deviceEnrollmentLimit" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="ownedDevices" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.directoryObject)" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="registeredDevices" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.directoryObject)" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="manager" Type="microsoft.graph.directoryObject" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="directReports" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.directoryObject)" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="memberOf" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.directoryObject)" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="createdObjects" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.directoryObject)" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="ownedObjects" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.directoryObject)" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="licenseDetails" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.licenseDetails)" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="transitiveMemberOf" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.directoryObject)" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="extensions" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.extension)" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="outlook" Type="microsoft.graph.outlookUser" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="messages" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.message)" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="mailFolders" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.mailFolder)" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="calendar" Type="microsoft.graph.calendar" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="calendars" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.calendar)" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="calendarGroups" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.calendarGroup)" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="calendarView" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.event)" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="events" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.event)" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="people" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.person)" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="contacts" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.contact)" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="contactFolders" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.contactFolder)" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="inferenceClassification" Type="microsoft.graph.inferenceClassification" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="photo" Type="microsoft.graph.profilePhoto" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="photos" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.profilePhoto)" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="drive" Type="microsoft.graph.drive" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="drives" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.drive)" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="planner" Type="microsoft.graph.plannerUser" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="onenote" Type="microsoft.graph.onenote" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="managedDevices" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.managedDevice)" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="managedAppRegistrations" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.managedAppRegistration)" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="deviceManagementTroubleshootingEvents" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.deviceManagementTroubleshootingEvent)" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="activities" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.userActivity)" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="insights" Type="microsoft.graph.officeGraphInsights" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="settings" Type="microsoft.graph.userSettings" ContainsTarget="true" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="joinedTeams" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.group)" ContainsTarget="true" />
      </EntityType>
```

The documentation lists all of those. There doesn't appear to be an global address book setting here unfortunately. If this is something you'd like to see on the Microsoft Graph. You can request it as a product feature request on User Voice as per https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/support

Comment: probably, this : <Property Name="showInAddressList" Type="Edm.Boolean" /> ?

Answer (score 3):

Folks,

The property to set where to show a user in the global address list **is** present and available in v1.0.  It's the `showInAddressList` property on the `user` resource. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties

`showInAddressList` Boolean

true if the Outlook global address list should contain this user, otherwise false. If not set, this will be treated as true. For users invited through the invitation manager, this property will be set to false.

Hope this helps,

Comment: The field visually shown in O365 Admin Portal, "Show in Global Address List" appears to be **computed** (not a one-to-one mapping). Toggling the setting in O365 Admin UI appears to set `HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled` (an Exchange Powershell flag), not the `showInAddressList` (MS Graph flag). Setting `showInAddressList` to false appears to reflect into O365 Admin interface. Seems like a bug/legacy behavior (setting MS Graph flags should be preferred over setting Exchange Powershell flags)

Answer (score 2):

I implemented it by the way (using `Microsoft.Graph` nuget package:

```
public class UserEx : User
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="showInAddressList")]
    public bool ShowInAddressList { get; set; }
}
```

then pass this object to `GraphClient`:

```
user.ShowInAddressList = false;
userResult = await _graphClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(user);
```

in result after registration:

[image]

thank you for Jeremy Thake MSFT !

Comment: glad I could help! I didn't notice that one there! Double checked and this was in the docs. I should've just done find in browser on that docs page for "global address list".

Comment: The field visually shown in O365 Admin Portal, "Show in Global Address List" appears to be **computed** (not a one-to-one mapping). Toggling the setting in O365 Admin UI appears to set `HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled` (an Exchange Powershell flag), not the `showInAddressList` (MS Graph flag). Setting `showInAddressList` to false appears to reflect into O365 Admin interface. Seems like a bug/legacy behavior (setting MS Graph flags should be preferred over setting Exchange Powershell flags)